# I have got a error message from uva online judge with compiler c++11 ... I never know why is this error generated

Tags: c++, compilation

This is the solution of problem in uva titled 'Combination Lcok'. I never know what is the problem about this code. I have got a message, "Compilation error for submission 20426328". I convince that this code must not have any problem. Please anybody tell me what is the problem. Moreover, this code work very well in my computer.

```
#include<cstdio>

int numbers[4];

int main() {
    while (true) {
        bool isEnd = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
        if (numbers[i] != 0)
            isEnd = false;
    }
    if (isEnd)
        break;
    int ret = 120;
    bool clockwise = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        int p1 = numbers[i], p2 = numbers[i + 1];
        if (p1 <= p2) {
            if (clockwise)
                ret += (p2 - p1);
            else
                ret += (40 - p2 + p1);
        }
        else {
            if (clockwise)
                ret += (40 - p1 + p2);
            else
                ret += (p1 - p2);
        }
        clockwise = !clockwise;
    }
    ret *= 9;
    printf("%d\n", ret);
  }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try adding `using namespace std;`

Comment: I already used it but, the error still is generated.

Comment: I too got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same verdict in a completely different question. And my code runs fine on my PC. Maybe is something going on with UVA... Let's wait to see what happens

Edit: I just submitted a solution with just a return 0 in the main, and verdict was compilation error. It's very likely it's a UVA problem

Comment: I know what is the problem. I think that internet explorer is the reason of the problem. I got AC by compiling my code with chrome not explorer.